# how to correctly build three.js website to load STL Files

Tags: build, three.js, vite, npx

[image]Hi Community,

I am building a website with Three.js for viewing STL file. Initially, I successfully managed to run the website on my localhost, where STL files were loading and displaying correctly. However,  I ran into issue: the STL files and canvas components are now missing without any error messages or warnings after `npx vite build` on live server.

I tried to rebuild project.  I've also noticed that when running `npx vite preview`, the canvas appears but without the STL files.

Thanks.

I tried to rebuild project a few times.
with npx vite build
[image]

with npx vite preview
[image]

Comment: Be careful when picking the tags, [tag:stl] is absolutely wrong to your question.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. i will remove it.